# Bootstrap <input> align top in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I align a bootstrap input field to top of a div?
I use a text input followed by a textarea with 3 rows.
Now i'd like input field and textarea with the same "top line".

Like this:

```
-----     -----
-----     

          -----
```

And NOT like this (in the middle of div):

```
          -----

-----     
-----

          -----
```

**CODE**

```
<form class="form form-inline">
  <!-- Label -->
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <label class="label label-danger">Kommentar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></label>
  </div>
  <!--Name input-->
    <input class="form-control col-md-offset-1" type="text" id="name_input" name="name_input" placeholder="Namn" required="">
    <textarea class="form-control col-md-offset-1" rows="3" id="input_text" name="text_input" placeholder="Kommentar.." required=""></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` will solved your issue.

Check your updated code here:

```css
.form-control.col-md-offset-1 {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<form class="form form-inline">
  <!-- Label -->
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <label class="label label-danger">Kommentar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></label>
  </div>
  <!--Name input-->
    <input class="form-control col-md-offset-1" type="text" id="name_input" name="name_input" placeholder="Namn" required="">
    <textarea class="form-control col-md-offset-1" rows="3" id="input_text" name="text_input" placeholder="Kommentar.." required=""></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i'd like to align my submit button at the bottom. I tried but with no succes...: https://jsfiddle.net/4g7cwc32/